# is it possible to reuse existing route table in cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am writing one cft to connect dynamodb uisng vpcEndpoint.

```
      DynamoDBEndpoint:
        Type: "AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint"
        Properties:
          RouteTableIds:
            - !Ref PublicRouteTable
            - !Ref Private0RouteTable
            - !Ref Private1RouteTable
            - !Ref Private2RouteTable
          ServiceName:
            !Sub "com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.dynamodb"
          VpcId: !Ref VPC

Parameters:
  vpcId:
    Description: Choose the existing one
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
```

I am getting existing vpcId by using parameter ,is there any way I can ruse my existing routetable ,Please suggest me on this how could I define this ref PublicRouteTable and ref PrivateRouteTable .

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? Also what you provided is invalid template.

Comment: Hi ,I only want to know how should I get this routetableId ?

Comment: You pass them as input parameters to your template.

Comment: How I will pass ?could u pls mention it ,because I am not getting any Id like vpc .

Comment: You have to know before  hand the ids. Its not clear from your question what do you really what to achieve. if you don't the route IDs, how do you expect to use them in your template?

Comment: perhaps u r not getting my question ,I do have routetable and vpc and subnets ,but is there any way to take it dynamically like parameter ,see in vpc I can choose ,same thing I want for routetable .I can hardcoded th value here which I dont want .

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you cant choose route tables dynamically in cloud formation, like you can do with vpc?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter `vpcId` works because it uses `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id` type which belongs to [Supported AWS-specific parameter types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types) in CloudFormation.

Sadly, CloudFormation [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types) similar type for route tables. You have to type out route tables IDs  manually in console when you specify parameters.